# How to add clickable links to a field in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

I have this admin.py

```
class LawyerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Name',   {'fields': ['last', 'first', 'firm_name', 'firm_url', 'school', 'year_graduated']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('last', 'first', 'school', 'year_graduated', 'firm_name', 'firm_url')
    list_filter = ['school', 'year_graduated']
    search_fields = ['last', 'school', 'firm_name']
```

and I want to make "firm_url" fields clickable with each of the url listed in the field. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: IMHO [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33616452/1472718) should be the right answer.

Comment: From what I can see the OP wanted links outside of the admin site. But that wasn't my case, so I ended up using `list_display_links`.

Comment: No, @ViniciusSilva, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616330/change-clickable-field-in-django-admin-list-display/33616452#33616452)'s not the answer IMHO.  The OP want a link to the value of the `firm_url` obviously, since, it is an url.

Comment: Seems like two different things, I came here via Google and for me the other answer  using `list_display_links` did the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58567807/12202624

Comment: @JohnWang Good point. At first, I thought you misunderstood the question, but I think others did actually. `list_display_links` links to the object for editing in the admin; not the value of the URL. Good catch!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Define a custom method in your LawyerAdmin class that returns the link as HTML:

```
def show_firm_url(self, obj):
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (obj.firm_url, obj.firm_url)
show_firm_url.allow_tags = True
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Comment: Use [Seppo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31745953/855050) instead. It is safer.

Comment: This is vulnerable to HTML injection. For example, `obj.firm_url` could be `http://example.com/<script>alert("I'm evil");</script>`

Comment: This is deprecated since django 1.11
Use `mark_safe` instead of `allow_tags`

Comment: This helps, I could see a seperate coloumn in Model Page. but how to use this in Template ? I've tried `{{ obj.show_firm_url}}` and it is not working . How should I incorporate this in templates ?

Comment: Here is a post for the up-to-date solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989257/1331671

Answer (score 155):

Use the `format_html` utility. This will escape any html from parameters and mark the string as safe to use in templates. The `allow_tags` method attribute has been deprecated in Django 1.9.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.display(description="Firm URL")
class LawyerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['show_firm_url', ...]
    ...

    def show_firm_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='{url}'>{url}</a>", url=obj.firm_url)
```

Now your admin users are safe even in the case of:

```
firm_url == 'http://a.aa/<script>eval(...);</script>'
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) for more info.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer since it prevents eval script attacks

Comment: If you want to open the link in a new tab and not the current window add target='_blank' to the <a> tag.

For example: format_html("<a href='{url}' target='_blank'>{url}</a>", url=obj.firm_url)

Comment: This should be the correct answer in 2023, also able to open in a new tab

Comment: Is it possible to make it model-independent, so that all fields to type URLField are displayed as links?

Answer (score 7):

add `show_firm_url` to `list_display`

Comment: Yes, I did and now it works, thanks. But it overrides the text display specified in my models and displays "show firm url" on the head of the column. I don't know if there is a way around it, but I changed "show_firm_url" to "Bio_link" and it's all fine now.

Answer (score 5):

> But it overrides the text display specified in my models and displays "show firm url" on the head of the column

You can change it by assigning short_description property:

```
show_firm_url.short_description = "Firm URL"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can handle it in the model if you prefer:

In models.py :

```
class Foo(models.Model):
...


     def full_url(self):
        url = 'http://google.com'
        from django.utils.html import format_html
        return format_html("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (url, url))
```

admin.py:

```
    list_display = ('full_url', ... )
```

Answer (score 1):

its more easy..

#in your admin.py add

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
```

##Code:

#url_file = "your field contain de url of file" example: http://127.0.0.1:8000
/backdown/respaldo.zip

```
list_display = ["url_file","download_content"]
#Link download
def download_content(self, obj):
    return format_html('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (obj.url_file, "Download"))

download_content.allow_tags = True
download_content.short_description = "Download Content File"
```

##in your html see like this..

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/backdown/respaldo.zip">http://127.0.0.1:8000/backdown/respaldo.zip</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that makes it easy to make all URL fields clickable:

```py
def format_url(url):
    return format_html("<a href='{url}'>{url}</a>", url=url)

# Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/53092940/2725810
def linkify(field):
    def _linkify(obj):
        linked_obj = getattr(obj, field.name)
        return format_url(linked_obj)

    _linkify.short_description = field.name  # Sets column name
    return _linkify

def linkified_list_display(model):
    result = []
    for f in model._meta.fields:
        if f.__class__ is URLField:
            result.append(linkify(field=f))
            continue
        result.append(f.name)
    return result

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = linkified_list_display(MyModel)
```