# admin template link with filter

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a link in the admin's html and It's pretty easy but I would like to add the filter `date today` on the link so that it would display all the info that has `date today`.

I have not tried anything yet as I am  unsure where to start, or is it possible? I'll update if I found something.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates/17232425

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`ModelAdmin.list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

In your `admin.py` add a `list_filter` for `date`:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('date',)
```

Comment: I have `list_filter`, but I am also using a notification app where it says what model has `date today` and is clickable and redirects it to the model that is already filtered

Comment: Sorry, then I don't get your question.

Comment: You can filter all the models via `list_filter` but I also want a clickable notification where on click it would redirect to the model with filter already set, sorry for not being clear, I do have the notification, I just need the filter part

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156114/how-do-i-add-a-custom-column-with-a-hyperlink-in-the-django-admin-interface

Comment: A bit close to it, but not what I am looking for, thanks though