# Give extra custom link to table row field for show other table data in django-admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have product and product details table where i put product details in product inline form. Now i want to add one extra link in product display table to show particular product details to show

[image]

Comment: i want to display product details page to show details of product in table format

Comment: its display <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/products/productdtails/1">1</a> in table row

Comment: I tried with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746128/8283848) and got expected result.

Comment: @JPG this code is work but when i click on this link i want to open product details in table view like number of qyt , color , price in this product. How can i display. Please help me i am new to django