# How to add columns through django admin panel

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a table named tableA with columns `"name"` and `"age"` built using `model.py`. 
Now I wanted to add another column like `"gender"` but this time not by changing model.py but directly through admin panel.
I know that admin panel allows to add values to the existing table but i wanted to add a feature where we can add columns too through the admin panel and not by hardcoding in `model.py`

So is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a custom column with a hyperlink in the django admin interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156114/how-do-i-add-a-custom-column-with-a-hyperlink-in-the-django-admin-interface)

Comment: No, coz i guess the link you mentioned wants to have a clickable column, and not add fields to the model dynamically through admin panel. What i want is to customize the admin panel so that it gives us option to add new fields directly through the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933596/django-dynamic-model-fields/7934577#7934577) about having dynamic models. I prefer JsonField to save data when I don't know the complete structure of model.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a view, which one connects to DB and you can write there a creating of any column for this table using raw SQL. 
But it's an awful way. In future, you will get an enormous count of different troubles. 
I'd better say: **it's not possible.**