# display one-to-many relationship for a model in Django admin (list mode)

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django admin site, when listing all the objects for a given model, I know we can customize which columns get displayed for a ModelA via `list_display`

Say that ModelA has a one-to-many relationship with ModelB. I would like to add another column on the listing page for ModelA, where each entry is a URL pointing to all objects of ModelB having a foreign key relationship on corresponding instance of Model A in that row. How can I achieve this customization with the admin app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a method to ModelA's admin class:

```
def modelb_link(self, inst):
    url = u'../modelb/?modela__id__exact=%d' % inst.id
    return u'<a href="%s">Models B</a>' % url
modelb_link.allow_tags = True
modelb_link.short_description = u'Models B'
```

In the url the 'modela__id__exact' part is a filter for list page, where 'modela' is the name of ForeignKey field, in ModelB class, that links to ModelA.

Then use this method in 'list_display' property and you are done. If you encounter any problems, just ask, I'll try to help.

Greetings,
Lukasz

Comment: Thanks for the help Lukasz. I tried your suggestion but hit this error:

ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
'ModelA_Admin.fields' refers to field '<function modelb_link at 0xa3e85dc>' that is missing from the form

class ModelA_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def modelb_link(self, inst):
        url = u'/'+settings.ADMIN_PREFIX + u'myapp/modelb/?foreignkey__id__exact=%d' % inst.id
        return u'<a href="%s">Models B</a>' % url
    modelb_link.allow_tags = True
    modelb_link.short_description = u'Models B'

    fields = ('field1', 'field2', modelb_link)

Comment: Nvm, my mistake I have to add "modelb_link" string to list_display. Also, settings.ADMIN_PREFIX was causing evaluation of the function to bail, so I removed it and hardcoded the admin URL. Now it's working as expected. Thanks again Lukasz!

Comment: You're right about ADMIN_PREFIX, it's not a standard Django setting value, I changed my answer a bit to fix it. Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it answers your question. Greets.

Comment: This was the one link that helped after searching quite a bit. However, the URL did not come in a clickable format in Django3. Finally modified to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin/31745953#31745953