# Taking relationships into account in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

If I had a One-To-Many relationship in Django, like the Django example at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#fields, A musician can have many albums, unique to that musician.

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

How would I go about implementing the following:

In Django, have 'Musicians' as a section to manage. When you go to manage musicians, you can edit the musician, or you can go on to the albums and manage the albums only for that musician. When you make a new album, the system automatically creates it for the musician you are on.
At the moment, you would have to manage albums individually from a huge list and choose the musician in the edit screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too complicated for the django admin as is, so either you explore the customization that the docs offers for you or you might consider not using the django admin at all and just write it as a part of your web app.

Check out http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, do you know of any nice methods for generating a similar admin interface using Django, but not the Django admin itself?

Comment: If you want to create another admin, check out the link above. But if you just want the look&feel, you can find the styles and templates in the django code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Admin inlines is one solution - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects - this will allow you to edit any Albums associated with the musician you are viewing or add a new one.

Comment: I have looked into this method, but I dont't want to edit the albums on the same page. I want to be editing the albums like normal, just somehow do it 'under' the artist and convey this to django when creating and saving models.

Comment: I found this, but not sure how to apply it in this instance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933693/display-one-to-many-relationship-for-a-model-in-django-admin-list-mode