# django admin: how to make a readonly url field clickable in change_form.html?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to make a readonly URL field clickable in the admin on a change_form page. I tried a widget, but soon realized widgets are for form fields only. So, before I try to solve this problem with jQuery (find and replace or something), I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution for this in python. Any ideas?

Comment: This question has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin

Comment: That's for list_display, not for change_form pages. I'm looking for a solution for a readonly url field on a change_form (edit model) page. Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add clickable links to a field in Django admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin)

Comment: Oops, just noticed this is from February 2011 ;-)

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but still deserves an answer.

[Ref the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields),
`readonly_fields` also supports those customization ways now, works just as [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin) posted in the comment:

```
def the_callable(obj):
    return u'<a href="#">link from the callable for {0}</a>'.format(obj)
the_callable.allow_tags = True

class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def the_method_in_modeladmin(self, obj):
         return u'<a href="#">link from the method of modeladmin for {0}</a>'.format(obj)
    the_method_in_modeladmin.allow_tags = True

    readonly_fields = (the_callable, 'the_method_in_modeladmin', 'the_callable_on_object')

ObjModel.the_callable_on_object = lambda self, obj: u'<a href="#">link from the callable of the instance </a>'.format(obj)
ObjModel.the_callable_on_object.__func__.allow_tags = True
```

The above code would render three readonly fields in its change form page then.

Comment: This is an excellent teaching example and should be marked as the answer.

Maybe worth a quick preface making it clear that you're showing three distinct ways to achieve the same thing. But great stuff. Thank you.

Answer (score 19):

The updated answer can be found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745953/2996101).

It uses the `format_html` [utility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) because `allow_tags` has been deprecated.

Also the docs for [ModelAdmin.readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) are really helpful.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.contrib import admin

class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('my_clickable_link',)

    def my_clickable_link(self, instance):
        return format_html(
            '<a href="{0}" target="_blank">{1}</a>',
            instance.<link-field>,
            instance.<link-field>,
        )

    my_clickable_link.short_description = "Click Me"
```

Answer (score 3):

I followed the link provided by okm and I managed to include a clickable link in change form page.

My solution (Add to admin.ModelAdmin, NOT models.model)

```
readonly_fields = ('show_url',)
fields = ('show_url',)

def show_url(self, instance):
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('ACTUAL_URL' + CUSTOM_VARIABLE, 'URL_DISPLAY_STRING')
show_url.short_description = 'URL_LABEL'
show_url.allow_tags = True
```

Answer (score 0):

## in admin.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin 
   from django.utils.html import format_html

   class Document(admin.ModelAdmin):
      readonly_fields = ["Document_url"]


      def Document_url(self, obj):
            return format_html("<a target='_blank',href='{url}'>view</a>",url=obj.document_url)
```