# Django admin : Storing links in database columns

Tags: django, django-admin

In my django admin I have a database column with different urls in each row. These urls are displayed as simple texts and not as link. How can I make them links so that they redirect the user to the url when they click on it.

Answer (score 1):

Set `allow_tags` on the method on the model to true:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def colored_name(self):
        return '<span style="color: #%s;">%s %s</span>' % (self.color_code, self.first_name, self.last_name)
    colored_name.allow_tags = True
```

from the [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display).

Answer (score 0):

**If you have access to your templates:**

If the contents of the `field` are something like:

```
http://www.google.com
```

You could output this in your template to make them clickable:

```
<a href="{{ field }}">{{ field }}</a>
```

**If not:**

I think this Stacko question is similar:  [How to add clickable links to a field in Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin)

Comment: i am using the django admin , i dont have any template