# How to add clickable links to open a folder/file in output of a print statement? (Python desktop application)

Tags: python, hyperlink, output

I wanted to add clickable links to python output. I am outputting the file path & it's contents. Can someone please tell me how to make them clickable, so that when user clicks on them to navigate there directly.

I found this one, but it's for Django web part of Python. I am looking for desktop links
[How to add clickable links to a field in Django admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin)

Thanks in advance,

Phani

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about straight forward Python, no frameworks? Why not just print what you want?
    `print('<a href="http://www.example.com">example text</a>')`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but only for win os.
As talking above you need to generate a link like this 'file:///C:/your/path/'

```
def show_firm_url(self, obj):
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (obj.firm_url, obj.firm_url)
show_firm_url.allow_tags = True
```

By the security reason there is no way to open your local folder via win explorer, so you need some toher software. I've use Local explorer addin for chrome.
But you can see an error when click on link if your path contains special symbols or non-english characters when generating url link because html convert this characters like '%0H' and this strings will not match with your local path. For this I have not answer.