# Change clickable field in Django admin list_display

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

In Django 1.8.6, by default, whenever I provide a `list_display` option to a ModelAdmin subclass, the first field in the list becomes clickable and leads to the object edit page.

Is there a way to keep the order of the fields in `list_display`, but change the clickable one?

Currently, I have the `id` field clickable (it goes first in `list_display`), which is a tad small. I would like to better click on, say, `name` to go to the edit page.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You could have a look at [django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links)

Basically it is used like

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birthday')
    list_display_links = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

Hope this will help :)