# Django : Escaping Html in Django Admin field?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to have a hyperlink in my Django Admin Dashboard. But Django admin is escaping the html.

admin.py

```
@admin.register(OrderReport)
class OrderReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('show_url', )
    list_display = ('__str__', 'show_url', )

    def show_url(self, obj):
        if obj.filepath:
            return "<a href='/reports/"+obj.filepath+"'>link</a>"
        return None
```

[image]

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949248/how-to-add-clickable-links-to-a-field-in-django-admin). But doesnt seem to work. I think allow_tags has been [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/). What are my options?

Comment: can you show me the code.. I think you can overwrite the templates..

Comment: @SancaKembang added in question body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

def show_url(self, obj):
    if obj.filepath:
        return format_html("<a href='/reports/"+obj.filepath+"'>link</a>")
    return None
```

Read more for this method [`here`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html).

This can be written more pythonic, of course:

```
return format_html('<a href="/reports/{}">link</a>', obj.filepath)
```

Comment: This was mentioned in the answer I linked in question. I tried it, didn't work. But now it works. Thanks.