# Django admin site add html link

Tags: django

admin.py

```
@admin.register(StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Student_Users', 'School_Year', '<a href="#">Report</a>')
    ordering = ('Education_Levels',)
    list_filter = ('Student_Users',)
```

[image]
I just want that to add the html link in the adminsite then if the admin click the "report"  it will filter what studentenrollmentrecord selected to html file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a method to calculate this field for each entry in the list, as follows:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

@admin.register(StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
class StudentsEnrollmentRecord(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('Student_Users', 'School_Year', 'report')
        ...

        def report(self, obj):
            return format_html(f'<a href={pass_link_here}>Report</a>')
```

Those kinds of methods take actual objects as a parameter, you can use it to create different links for different objects. `obj.field_name`